# Object passing in a new thread python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am facing problem with tkinter. I declared root = tkinter.Tk(). Then I want to run a canvas widget in a new thread. Problem is passing root object. Is there any solution?`

```
root = tkinter.Tk()
def f():
    text = StringVar() 
    scrollView=Label(root,height=1,width=20,bg="white",
    textvariable=text,anchor=NW)
    scrollView.pack()

    scrollString = "This is a test. Woking with pi. This is a great tool for 
    developing any handy device."
    #Time delay between chars, in milliseconds
    for i in range(len(scrollString)+1):
        s = scrollString[i:]
        text.set(s)
        sleep(.1)
        root.update()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=f)
print "Starting thread"
t1.start()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you run your own code alongside Tkinter's event loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/459083/how-do-you-run-your-own-code-alongside-tkinters-event-loop)

Comment: note that the callback passed to ".after" should be responsible for a single update, not a whole loop of updates.

Comment: Do not forget to declare `global root`  in `f()`

Comment: `global root` is not working @BillalBEGUERADJ

Comment: Script is running fine when I am declaring `tkinter.Tk()` object inside another thread where `.update` attributed.. But I need to declare it in main thread. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: you cannot "run a canvas widget in a new thread". All tkinter widgets must be created and manipulated in the same thread.

Comment: @ZulkarNayem prehaps on your system but the exact code run on my machine gives me the error: `RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop`, tkinter is not stable with threads.

Comment: Yes you are right. I also think so. @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen